# Sublime Text : Use Emacs Indentations

Tags: emacs, indentation, sublimetext2, auto-indent

I am a fervent user of Emacs, but i switch sometimes on Sublime Text for bigs projects who have 20+ files. Sublime Text is an excellent Text Editor, but i love Emacs Indentation on C / C++ files.

I did a small search on Google to see how to implement the SmartTab indentation of Emacs in sublime text, but no one did this in the past.

I see the configuration of smarttab, http://emacswiki.org/emacs/SmartTabs, but i dont know how to implement this on Sublime Text.

Someone already did this or have any idea?

Comment: may I introduce you to `M-x ibuffer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sublime text is pretty.  If you're productive in it, then by all means keep using it.  I don't know if it has an indentation engine remotely close to cc-mode, though.

On the other hand, there is NO WAY Emacs has an upper limit of 20 open files or whatever.  Power users very often have hundreds of files open at the same time.  If you have trouble managing many files in Emacs, maybe that's what you should be trying to resolve.